# My React app is "can't reach this page" in my browser

Tags: reactjs, npm, browser

I created a react app and all was well until I restarted my laptop and whenever I run `npm start` it shows "can't reach page" in the browser.
I've switched browsers still the same result. Please can anyone point me to a possible solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with my code, I just barely npx created a new react app. It works fine on other people's laptop but not mine